# Making a well formated responsive form with Boostrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new in CSS in general, so please be forgiving. I am trying to make a form with ASP.Net MVC (with Razor) that would look like this :

[image]

This old form was made in the past with numerous table, tr, td ,p and br tags, with fixed width, so the end result was exactly as expected, but only for a screen of a certain size. The end result in anything except a screen of more then 1024x768 is pretty bad since the user has to do a lot of scrolling, both vertically and horizontally.

What I would like to do is to replicate this visual on big screen, but in a responsive way, meaning it will line up differently on a tablet or a phone. I am using ASP.net with MVC 5 and the bootstrap css. However, I am having trouble replicating the layout (Label on top, control below it).

So my question is this : What it a rough html for this (with bootstrap css). Can anybody recommend a good tutorial on bootstrap and css in general ? I know there are a lot, but which one are actually goods ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap classes are the way to go. The documentation is good enough, really. It's very easy to pick up and incredibly easy to write. Your example in Bootstrap 4 classes:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column">
 <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column pb-1">
  <label class="font-italic" for="reference">Reference</label>
  <span class="text-black-50">Votre numero de contrat ou le nom de famille</span>
  <input class="" id="reference" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column pb-1">
  <label class="font-italic" for="enterprise">Enterprise *</label>
  <input class="" id="enterprise" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div class="d-flex flex-row pb-1">
  <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column">
   <label class="font-italic" for="address1">Adresse *</label>
   <input class="" id="address1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="w-50 w-50 d-flex flex-column">
   <label class="font-italic" for="address2">Adresse</label>
   <input class="" id="address2" type="text" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The classes included here would probably account for more than half of your code later on. I make extensive use of the `d-flex` class that turns it into a flex-box. `pb-1` stands for padding bottom, 1 rem, `w-50` means width 50%. The only gotcha is  `flex-row` divides the child elements into separate columns, and flex-column divides it into rows.

Enjoy using Bootstrap, it's really awesome.

Comment: You have my upvote, since there are few people that read questions related to Bootstrap...

Comment: Thanks. I'm amazed by what I might need that already exist in Bootstrap. For anyone else reading, you can combine the flex classes above with the one in the example @D.Smania showed below to create flex layouts that have set column sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and also) with Bootstrap, you can use the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), this is based on `row` and `col-*` classes. Check the next example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <label class="font-italic" for="reference">
        Référence
        <br>
        <small class="text-muted">Votre número de contrat ou le nom de famille</small>
      </label>          
      <input class="form-control" id="reference" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-6">
      <label class="font-italic" for="enterprise">Enterprise *</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="enterprise" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">        
    <div class="col-6">
      <label class="font-italic" for="address1">Adresse *</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="address1" type="text" />
    </div>        
    <div class="col-6">
      <label class="font-italic" for="address2">Adresse</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="address2" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which one is better , the grid or flex system. Flex system seems more complete, but more complex...

Comment: @DavidBrunelle for a responsive site, usually I use the grid system as the base, and then, for particular cases or goals, I complete with flex classes and the other utilities that Bootstrap offers. You have `navbars`, `modals`, `boxes`, `cards`, and lot of others things whitin the framework. But, this is only my recommendation, of course.